# Is it common for DHCPv6 and RA to provide IPv6 addr in the same subnet?

Tags: ipv6, dhcpv6, icmpv6

For IPv6, both DHCP and RA (the "prefix information" option, with the A flag) can provide IPv6 addresses to hosts. I'm still confused if it's common for DHCPv6 and RA to provide IP addresses in the same subnet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's common not to hand out addresses with DHCPv6 at all. In the cases where DHCPv6 is used to configure addresses the A-flag is usually turned off. But what you describe is possible too.

I have seen it where enterprise admins wanted devices to have a predictable addresses for remote management, but also wanted to support Android, which doesn't support DHCPv6. Both can use the same prefix, but configuring two prefixes is also possible. Usually having multiple prefixes is considered to be more confusing than helpful.

In short: all of these options are valid in IPv6. It's up to the network admin to determine what the best configuration is.